# Can a Variable Be Both Dependent and Independent?

Tags: predictor, lags, quantile-regression, dependent-variable, eviews

[image]

We can see that the GDP growth, represented by "y" is the dependent variable and independent variable. I would like to perform quantile regression in Eviews, with `y = FC + y + c` , and the coefficient for y is 1, which make sense. Do I have to do something like  `y(+4) = FC + y + c` if I wish to get the h quarter ahead?

Comment: Yes, and no.  What's happening in the time series equation above is that the prediction for $y$ at time period $t+h$ is dependent on the the value of $y$, $h$ series previous (the value of $y$ at time period $t$).  Software specific question like that on Eviews are better for stack overflow.  Different software systems require handling time periods for time series data differently, and I'm not familiar with EVIEWS.  However, you will likely need to use the LEAD and LAG variables in EVIEWS based on a cursory review of online documentation:  https://forums.eviews.com/viewtopic.php?t=8634.

Comment: Thank you @StatsStudent

Comment: Regarding the title question, albeit not so much the context in the body, another case could be mediation analyses, in which $m$ is seen as both a result of $x$ and a subsequent cause of $y$.  More generally, variables in complicated SEM analyses can play multiple roles.

Answer (score 9):

The notation is discussing two different time periods.

$y_t$ refers to the GDP at some time $t$.

$y_{t+q,b}$ refers to the GDP at some other time.

These are measurements of different quantities.

Comment: It's probably worth saying also that $y_t$ and $y_{t+1}$, etc are different random variables, there is no single $y$ random variable, but a series of random varaibles.